# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content solution without affecting responsiveness and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content solution without affecting responsiveness and performance

I was searching for solution but I found that we needs css and js before actual page load for responsive If we delayed the page load then it may leads to performance issue ?

suggest me solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this script just before the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "yourscript.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", scriptAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", scriptAtOnload);
else window.onload = scriptAtOnload;
</script>
```

yourscript.js is your external script.

This will make sure that the script is loaded only after the entire document is loaded.